# ng command not found (@angular/cli 1.0.0)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I tried to install angular/cli the newest version 1.0.0.
I could succeed to install with `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` easily.
However, I could see `'ng command not found'` when I use `ng` command.

I use zsh. Here's my zshrc.
I wrote this in my zshrc.
`export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/6.10.2/bin:$PATH"`

If you have any idea to solve this issue, please let me know.
Thanks! :D

Comment: after installation andseeting the path did you restart your terminal or command prompt

Comment: @Aravind, Of course I did it like that :(

Comment: **what ng command you are trying?** and root folder of your terminal points to?

Comment: @Aravind, I tried to make ng project folder so I tried `ng new test`

Comment: your installation had any warnings or errors or mismatch ?

Comment: Not at all. Everything was fine when I installed angular/cli

Comment: I think it's path issue, but I have no idea what I have to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141914/discussion-between-aravind-and-mingyu-jeon).

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution finally.
As I mentioned, it was path issue.
I just didn't know how to fix this problem.
I hope it helps others who suffer from the same problem as me.
I fellow next steps, and the issue's gone.

**First, remove node you installed**

1. `npm config get prefix`
2. `cd [the path you get above]`
3. `cd lib && rm -rf node_modules`
4. `cd /usr/local/lib && sudo rm -rf node*`
5. `cd /usr/local/include & sudo rm -rf node*`
6. `brew uninstall node (if you installed node with brew)`
7. `cd /usr/local/bin`
8. `sudo rm -rf npm`
9. `sudo rm -rf node`

Just in case,
10. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1`
11. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d`
12. `sudo rm -rf ~/.npm`

**Second, Install node.js again on website.**
**Third, Install @angular/cli**
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

**Fourth, check node path where you installed.**
`npm get prefix`

**Fifth, edit your path on zshrc or bashrc, whatever you're using.**
`alias ng="**/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lib**/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"`

**It's done!**

that is not a good solution.
Does not work with ng new or other command.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

then removed ng from /usr/local/bin and then re-installed the angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

`npm install npm@latest -g`
 and removed `ng` from `/usr/local/bin`
and re-install `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Done!